# How do I access coverage.py results programmatically?

Tags: python, coverage.py

Using [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.org) I can produce a report that looks like:

```
Name                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------
my_program.py                20      4    80%   33-35, 39
my_other_module.py           56      6    89%   17-23
-------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        76     10    87%
```

How do I programmatically access the value of `87` from the coverage results data to use as an input to another program?

Comment: In the API there is the function `CoverageData::run_infos()`, which will return the data collected during a single run as a dict. Hope it helps

Comment: This is a very valuable question in terms of enforcing 100% on a CI system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will assume that you have already run

```
$ coverage run my_program.py arg1 arg2
```

and want to use the data it measured. `Coverage.report()` returns the total as a floating-point number (you can take it, or round it to a whole percentage if you like).
But the function prints a report on the screen. To avoid that, we will open a file object to the null device to suck it up.

```
import coverage
import os
cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.load()

with open(os.devnull, "w") as f:
    total = cov.report(file=f)

print("Total: {0:.0f}".format(total))
```